How to remove colored area between rainbow and the axis on raibow chart
I am trying to create a Bitcoin Rainbow price chart in html and Javascript. I am able to create the chart but there is a filled area under the rainbow (between rainbow and the axis).
Following is my chart function:

        function createChart(data) {
            const dates = data.map(d => d.date);
            const prices = data.map(d => d.price);

            const rainbowLevels = [
                { color: '#C00200', key: 'maxBubble', label: 'Maximum bubble territory' },
                { color: '#D64018', key: 'sell', label: 'Sell. Seriously, sell!' },
                { color: '#ED7D31', key: 'fomo', label: 'FOMO intensifies' },
                { color: '#F6B45A', key: 'bubble', label: 'Is this a bubble?' },
                { color: '#FEEB84', key: 'hold', label: 'HOLD' },
                { color: '#B1D580', key: 'stillCheap', label: 'Still cheap' },
                { color: '#63BE7B', key: 'accumulate', label: 'Accumulate' },
                { color: '#54989F', key: 'buy', label: 'BUY!' },
                { color: '#4A7DD7', key: 'fireSale', label: 'Fire sale!' }
            ];

            const series = rainbowLevels.map(level => ({
                name: level.label,
                type: 'line',
                data: data.map(d => [d.date, d[level.key]]),
                areaStyle: {
                    color: level.color,
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                lineStyle: {
                    width: 0
                },
                showSymbol: false
            }));

            series.push({
                name: 'BTC Price',
                type: 'line',
                data: prices.map((price, index) => [dates[index], price]),
                lineStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                    width: 1
                },
                showSymbol: false,
                smooth: true,
                yAxisIndex: 1
            });

            const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

            const option = {
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    left: 'center'
                },
                
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'axis',
                    formatter: function (params) {
                        let tooltip = `<div>${params[0].axisValueLabel}</div>`;
                        params.forEach(param => {
                            tooltip += `
                                <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                                    <span style="background-color: ${param.color}; width: 8px; height: 8px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 4px;"></span>
                                    ${param.seriesName}: ${param.value[1]}
                                </div>`;
                        });
                        return tooltip;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    data: ['BTC Price', ...rainbowLevels.map(level => level.label)],
                    top: 20,
                    orient: 'horizontal'
                },
                grid: {
                    top: 80,
                    left: 60,
                    right: 40,
                    bottom: 60,
                    containLabel: true
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'time',
                    name: 'Date'
                },
                yAxis: [
                    {
                        type: 'log',
                        name: 'Price (log scale)',
                        min: 0.01,
                        max: 1000000,
                        splitLine: { show: false }
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'log',
                        name: '',
                        min: 0.01,
                        max: 1000000,
                        axisLabel: { show: false },
                        axisLine: { show: false },
                        splitLine: { show: false },
                        axisTick: { show: false }
                    }
                ],
                dataZoom: [
                    {
                        type: 'inside',
                        xAxisIndex: [0]
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'slider',
                        xAxisIndex: [0],
                        start: 0,
                        end: 100
                    }
                ],
                series: series
            };

            chart.setOption(option);
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                chart.resize();
            });
        }


here  is how it looks like in the browser. As you can see there is a filled area with blue color. Also when I hover on one of the legend elements (on top) It the filled area changes the color. For example on hovering over 'Sell. Seriously, sell!' the filled area color changes to Orange and so on.
I have tried to change the values in the following. I change the color to #ffffff but it makes the rainbow disappear as well or make it white also.
              areaStyle: {
                    color: level.color,
                    opacity: 1,
                   },

How can I get rid of the filled area under the rainbow while keeping the colors of the rainbow curves?

can you not just add another rainbow stripe at the end with color: 'transparent'?

Alternative solution is stacked area chart. But you need to build a custom tooltip.

